# pl sql sort by calculation formula of multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

my table fields like this:

| id | name | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

and the formula is: weight/(height*height)

So my question is how can I sort my data after the calculation formula? I want to create an anonymous block. Inside the block, I will create a variable then i will set the result and finally I will sort by the result. But I don't know actually how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code please.

Comment: I couldn't edit question but my code is in here: DECLARE
id NUMBER :=0;
weight NUMBER :=0;
height NUMBER :=0;

BEGIN

SELECT p.id,
       p.weight,
 p.height
INTO
id,
weight,
height
 from p
       
END

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just display the result, then a loop (through the table) with `dbms_output.put_Line` call does the job:

```
SQL> select * from p;

        ID NAME       HEIGHT     WEIGHT
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         1 Little          2        110
         2 Foot          1.8         90
         3 Asked         1.6         70

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select name,
  3                         round(weight / (height * height), 1) result
  4                  from p
  5                  order by result)
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.name ||': '|| cur_r.result);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
Asked: 27.3
Little: 27.5
Foot: 27.8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PL/SQL for this and can do it in SQL.

Either use the formula in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       height,
       weight,
       ROUND(weight / height / height, 3)
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY
       ROUND(weight / height / height, 3)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, name, height, weight) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 1.5,  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 1.6, 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 1.7,  72 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 1.8, 150 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | ROUND(WEIGHT/HEIGHT/HEIGHT,3) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | Carol | 1.7 | 72 | 24.913 |
> | 1 | Alice | 1.5 | 60 | 26.667 |
> | 4 | Debra | 1.8 | 150 | 46.296 |
> | 2 | Betty | 1.6 | 120 | 46.875 |

Or, give the column an alias and then use the alias in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       height,
       weight,
       ROUND(weight / height / height, 3) AS bmi
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY bmi
```

Which, for the same sample data, outputs:

> | ID | NAME | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | BMI |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | Carol | 1.7 | 72 | 24.913 |
> | 1 | Alice | 1.5 | 60 | 26.667 |
> | 4 | Debra | 1.8 | 150 | 46.296 |
> | 2 | Betty | 1.6 | 120 | 46.875 |

If you do want to use PL/SQL then you can wrap it in a `CURSOR` or use `BULK COLLECT INTO` to put it into a collection.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0e573f5a74fd76b3bc8572665c4c6dd7)*